# Resharper and linting C# in Unity

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm currently trying to figure out what's wrong with my Resharper.
I want Reshaper to lint my C# code. I edit the code in Visual Studio 2019 but it stems from Unity, i.e. it's mostly MonoBehaviours and the like.
Does this affect linting? I don't see any linting at all rn. I can literally type `int = b;` and don't even get any sloppy remarks...

I don't have Resharper suspended, I checked the code highlighting settings and everything seems to be on.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have not setup as described here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/intellisense-not-working-with-visual-studio-fix.836599/

> Step 1:
> Close Visual Studio
>
> Step 2:
> In Unity, go to Edit < Preferences < External Tools (left part of the Window)
>
> Step 3:
> In External Tools go to the part that says External Script Editor (this should be on which ever Visual Studio editor you are using (for me it defaulted to "Open by File Extension"
>
> Step 4:
> Make sure Generate all csproj files is checked, and Editor Attaching is checked
>
> Step 5:
> Open the C# script you were trying to open earlier

Comment: Cheers! Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers.

Comment: I gotta say though that this isn't 100% correct, as, at least for me, some of the options don't seem to exist anymore. It still helped with the problem insofar, as I realised that VS didn't recognise the scripts to be C#. What I did in the end was starting up another C# project outside of Unity, turn Resharper Off and On again and somehow that did it for me... IT Crowd would be proud of me.